# Задача со строками из ЕГЭ

Tags: c++

Текстовый файл 24-s1.txt состоит не более чем из 10^6 заглавных латинских букв (A..Z). Текст разбит на строки различной длины. Определите количество строк, в которых буква K встречается чаще, чем буква U.

Получается неправильный ответ, вот код:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("24-s1.txt");
    string s; getline(fin, s);
    int c = 0;
    int u = 0;
    int k = 0;
    //Определите количество строк, в которых буква K встречается чаще, чем буква U.

    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == 'K') k++;
        if (s[i] == 'U') u++;
        if (k > u) c++;
    }

    cout << c;
```

В чем ошибка?

Comment: Отдельный цикл по считыванию. Потом цикл по буквам в вашем случае

Comment: Ваш с должен выйти выше уровнем всех циклов а его инкремент на первом цикле.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должно быть что то такое по логике

```
ifstream fin("24-s1.txt");
string s; 
int c = 0;

//Определите количество строк, в которых буква K встречается чаще, чем буква U.
while(getline(fin, s)) {
 int u = 0;
 int k = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
 {
    if (s[i] == 'K') k++;
    if (s[i] == 'U') u++;
    
 }
 if (k > u) c++;
}

cout << c;
```

Извините но проверить не могу поскольку с телефона